# PHP Captcha image is not loaded in live server

Tags: php, captcha

Everything is fine till the last week. But suddenly the captcha used in my server is not working. The captcha image is not loaded on every page in this server only. But I tried this same code in another server but that is working fine.

Maybe this can happen because of the hosting server fault? I tried a sample one in this server: http://www.uvs.co.in/cms/newcap/

Captcha Code (**captcha.php**):

```
<?php
session_start();
$code=rand(1000,9999);
$_SESSION["code"]=$code;
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 24);
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 22, 86, 165);
$fg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $bg);
imagestring($im, 5, 5, 5,  $code, $fg);

header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Form code:

```
<form action="validate.php" method="post">
Enter Image Text
    <input name="captcha" type="text">
    <img src="captcha.php" /><br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: @webpic I added in the question on editing.Take a look on that

Comment: The should work. Are there any errors in your error logs? Else try enable error reporting and see if it throws an error.

Comment: @Tom Udding There is no error in error log..can this kind of error can happens because of the server fault? because this same code is working fine in another server

Comment: Is error logging enabled? can you please cross check the same?

Comment: And I have checked this and working on the link you shared here;

Answer (score 1):

Gd library must be installed in the server. Please check your live server configuration for this.

Comment: Ok then please check PNG is enabled or not in GD library.